# How to add transition to sections on my website

Tags: infinite-scroll

I am making a custom-coded site. I want to add a transition to sections when they come into the viewport. I am not sure if it's called lazy loading or infinite scroll. I am adding an example theme from ThemeForest:

https://wpresidence.net/

You can see that when you scroll down the heading and images become visible with a slight transition. How can I do this on my site?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea from where to start. Tried a bunch of online solutions but they all only work on images.

Comment: This site is good at answering concrete questions rather than broad ones. Try to focus on a specific part of your problem.

Comment: I just want to add transitions to html sections. even if you can provide any link where it is explained how to do it, that would work for me. These transitions are there in all the websites these days. If you see the themeforest theme's link that I added, you will know what exactly I need. Also, sorry for asking a very broad question, this is my first time posting a question on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could very easily be solved using a `scroll` event listener on `window`, tracking exactly when a given HTML section comes into view and then add a class on it that fades it in.

Or as a much more simpler method, which I'll prefer, you could use the `IntersectionObserver` API. It allows us to track given elements entering or exiting a reference element, which could be the viewport as well.

`IntersectionObserver` can help you determine very easily when a given element enters the viewport. And when that happens, you could add a class on the element to trigger a transition.

You can learn more about `IntersectionObserver` at [Advanced JavaScript - `IntersectionObserver` - CodeGuage](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/advanced-js/intersection-observer-introduction), and more about the scroll event at [JavaScript Scroll Event - CodeGuage](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/events-scroll-event).

As per the CSS to use to power this feature, you'll initially apply `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0` to an HTML element, and then once it enters the viewport, add a class that changes these properties to `visibility: visible` and `opacity: 1`. Keep in mind that the HTML element must have a `transition` set in order to get these properties to be changed *smoothly*.

Comment: thnx a lot man. this worked

Answer (score 0):

```
  
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
    entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting){
      console.log(entry);
      entry.target.style.opacity  = 1;
      entry.target.style.visibility  = "visible";
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
    });
  }, {rootMargin: "0px 0px -400px 0px"});
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => { observer.observe(img) });
```

How can I change 'querySelectorAll' to 'getelementsbyclassname'. How to write the last line of code then? if i just replace 'img' with the class name it doesnt work